# Change textfield attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the textfield attribute.

My script is working fine.

But now I'm trying to change this part `name='kadnya[]'` to this `name='kadnya['pudge']'` or `name='kadnya['drow']'` depending on the table row. How can I achieve that?

Please check my script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addRow").click(function() {
    $(".rowadded").append("<td></td>" +
      "<td><input type='text' class='kd' name='kadnya[]'></td>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <table id="tablekd">
    <tr>
      <td>Pudge</td>
      <td class="rowadded"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drow</td>
      <td class="rowadded"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <button type="button" id="addRow">Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), then you can grab the index of the row you are adding to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addRow").click(function() {
    $(".rowadded").each(function(index,$row) {
      var name = $(this).prev().text(); // or $(this).parent().first().text();
      $(this).after("<td></td>" +
      "<td><input type='text' class='kd' name='kadnya["+name+"]'></td>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <table id="tablekd">
    <tr>
      <td>Pudge</td>
      <td class="rowadded"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drow</td>
      <td class="rowadded"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <button type="button" id="addRow">Add</button>
</form>
```

Or

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addField").click(function() {
    $(".inputCell").each(function(index,$row) {
      var name = $(this).prev().text(); // or $(this).parent().first().text();
      $(this).append("<input type='text' class='kd' name='kadnya["+name+"]' />");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <table id="tablekd">
    <tr>
      <td>Pudge</td>
      <td class="inputCell"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drow</td>
      <td class="inputCell"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <button type="button" id="addField">Add input</button>
</form>
```

Comment: well, i have edit my question. My bad. Can i change the `name` with the `$(this).parent().siblings(":first").text()`

Comment: We have to not append but do after instead or put the rowadded class on the TR and change to $(this).first().text

Comment: thanks. I have a question. I don't want to create another `<td></td>` I just want to add the input text. Can i ?

Comment: Yes - append the input to the cell if you need

Comment: i'm trying to implemented your code. But it's keep adding 4 input. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/0pckt5v3/